# Is there a way to copy and paste last row n amount of times faster? The row contains formulas

Tags: excel, vba, select, copy

I am currently trying to copy and paste last row a number amount of times n. So far the code is working good, but the iteration is very slow! even if there are few rows to be copied. Could you please guys advice on how to improve timing on this one? Instead of iterarion, can I directly copy this 3 times?

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To n
    lRow = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    n = 3

    Ws.Range("A" & lRow).EntireRow.Copy Ws.Range("A" & lRow + 1)   
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve timing in Copy and Pasting in Excel, you can try adding

```
application.screenupdating=False
application.calculation=xlmanual
```

to the beginning of the code and add

```
application.screenupdating=True
application.calculation=xlautomatic
```

to the end (restore to normal)

Answer (score 0):

Just resize the range you want to paste in using `.Resize(RowSize:=n)` so you don't need to loop.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyMultiplePaste()
    Const n = 3
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ws.Range("A" & lRow).EntireRow.Copy ws.Range("A" & lRow + 1).Resize(RowSize:=n)
End Sub
```

Additionally you can use `.Offset` instead of `lRow + 1`

```
Public Sub CopyMultiplePaste2()
    Const n = 3
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
        .EntireRow.Copy .Offset(RowOffset:=1).Resize(RowSize:=n)
    End With
End Sub
```